# Same structure,different files but still Compile Error?

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, compiler-errors

Hi can someone actually find the wrong syntax here. As i run the VB code, it kept saying compiling error and highlighting the syntax Controls. Tried the same code before at different files and runs smoothly.

Here are the codes that are functioning:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cntr As Integer
Dim sh  As Worksheet
Dim cntr2 As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim cntr3 As Integer

cntr3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C"))
cntr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A17:BL17"))
cntr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A19:BL19"))

For i = 5 To cntr
    For y = 20 To cntr3
        If Cells(17, i).Value = "DC Test" And Worksheets(1).cbDevice_List.Value = Cells(y, 3).Value Then
            For z = i To cntr
                For x = 1 To 17
                    If Controls("tb" & x).Value = "" Then
                        Select Case Cells(y, z).Interior.ColorIndex
                            Case 3: Controls("tb" & x).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                                Controls("tb" & x).Value = "Failed"
                            Case 4: Controls("tb" & x).ForeColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                                Controls("tb" & x).Value = "Passed"
                            Case Else: Controls("tb" & x).Value = "N/A"
                        End Select
                        z = z + 1
                    End If
                Next x
            Next z
        End If
    Next y
Next i

end sub
```

and here are the one that are not functioning:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim cntr As Integer
Dim cntr2 As Integer
Dim z As Integer

cntr = Range("C23", Range("C23").End(xlDown)).Count
cntr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D22:T22"))
For i = 0 To cntr
    If Worksheets(2).list_device.Value = Range("C23").Offset(i, 0).Value Then
        For z = 0 To cntr2
            For y = 1 To 20
                If Controls("TextBox" & y).Value = "" Then
                    Select Case Range("C23").Offset(i, z).Interior.ColorIndex
                        Case 3: Controls("TextBox" & y).ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                            Controls("TextBox" & y).Value = "Failed"
                        Case 4: Controls("TextBox" & y).ForeColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                            Controls("TextBox" & y).Value = "Passed"
                        Case Else: Controls("TextBox" & y).Value = "Wrong Handler"
                    End Select
                    z = z + 1
                End If
            Next y
        Next z
    End If
Next i

end sub
```

Both do have the same goal but slight different on integer definition. Really appreciate ones help.

I tried change the name of each TextBox but still doesnt work. Can someone help me with the error?

Comment: Did you put the code in a `UserForm` where is needs to be? Or did you maybe put it into a module or a worksheet or something?

Comment: Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and use it to correctly indent your code.

Comment: I doubt that the first part compiles - there is no sub or function ... nor is `i` dimmed ...

Comment: Already edited the full code including the sub

Comment: how can the first one compile: `i` is not dimmed. Where do you get the compile error in the second part?

Comment: i am quite new to stackoverflow. What is the i? the compile error on the second part is the Controls syntax.

Comment: Where is the second code located?

Comment: second code located in different workbook. the first one located in an userform.

Comment: Second code needs to be in a userform...

Comment: Why does it need to be in userform? any explanation for it?

Comment: `Controls` is a member of `UserForm`, but the `WorkSheet` class doesn't have a `Controls` collection.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/controls-collection-microsoft-forms   Worksheets have an `OLEObjects` collection which is similar - you can use that instead of `Controls`

Comment: ahh nice. Thanks for the knowledge and tips too! really appreciate it